# When do fundamental C++ types have an unknown initial value?

Tags: c++, initialization, standards, built-in-types

When will a fundamental C++ type, such as `int` or `float`, have an unknown initial value?

How does the type of memory allocation factor in, if at all?  What about the declaration?  What if it's a member of a `class`/`struct`/`union`?  Is C++11 different from C++03 or C++98?

I have my suspicions, but no idea if my knowledge is complete (or correct, for that matter)

Comment: Well, it depends on the type of initialization. Value initialization will zero them. You can then see when value initialization is used, such as `int i{};`.

Comment: An uninitialized variable will have an unknown initial value, except if it is static or global (in which case it is initialized to all bits 0).

Comment: *implicit* is not a term that can be applied to types (at least in the standard). You might want to use *fundamental* types or *POD* (plain old data) which include both *fundamental* types and some user defined types composed only of *fundamental* types in a limited set of ways (these share most of the properties of the *fundamental* types). I also provided a list of cases in an answer to your previous question.

Comment: Related to [Has C++ standard changed with respect to the use of indeterminate values and undefined behavior in C++14?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801) in C++14 they clarified a lot about indeterminate values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) data (including all fundamental types) will have an unknown value when both:

- it doesn't have [static memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_memory_allocation) (it's instead created on the stack or with `new`)
- it isn't initialized, including empty initialization and/or constructor initialization lists

Global/static variables, of all types, are set to zero as part of the startup process before `main` is called. Constructors are called for types that have constructors before `main` [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure).

Anything not initialized in the constructor is also unknown.

**Edit:** to clarify, `std::string` is a good example of "constructor not initializing everything" - if you have a local `std::string str;`, then `str` will have a defined "empty string" content, but the content of the actual buffer, or indeed what the buffer points at may not be set to anything meaningful at all - as the implementation may determine based on the length [or some other way] whether there is a buffer available or not once we start using the string to store stuff].

**Edit2:** As the comment explains, you can also have "hybrid" cases, where parts of a structure is being initialized, e.g. a `struct` that contains some elements of "plain data" and some elements that have constructors. The ones that have constructors will have their constructor called. The plain data will not be initialized.

[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) It may well be that the code running constructors is part of, or called from inside the "main" function - but if that is the case, it will be "before any of your code in main is started".

Comment: +1 for taking a stab at it... it is hard to provide a precise definition of what and when will be initialized. The rules for initialization are complex and with a good amount of corner cases (for example, `struct S { int i; std::string s; };` does not have a user-provided constructor and is not a POD, and it will only be *partly* initialized if no initializer is provided for the instance.

Comment: Yes, so `std::string` falls under "Anything not initialized by the constructor" [parts of a the string, such as length/size is initialized, but the string buffer may be just about anything the implementation likes - uninitilized, point to NULL, point to uninitialized data on heap, or something else].

Comment: In the example above `std::string` will be *initialized* by the constructor (whatever the meaning of initialized that the implementor coded, which in the case of `std::string` is probably the whole thing), but the `i` is what will *not* be initialized.

Comment: Will automatically generated default constructors initialize these members?

Comment: No, autamtically generated constructors don't initialize member variables of plain types.

Answer (score 2):

From "Working Draft C++, 2012-11-02"

> **3.6.2 Initialization of non-local variables [basic.start.init]**
>   2 Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5)
>   before any other initialization takes place.

Variables with static storage are *at least* zero initialized.

> **3.7.3 Automatic storage duration [basic.stc.auto]**
>   2 [ Note: These variables are initialized and destroyed as described in 6.7. — end note ]

6.7 says nothing about *how* automatic variables are initialized.

> **3.7.4 Dynamic storage duration [basic.stc.dynamic]**
>   ...
>   **3.7.4.1 Allocation functions [basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]**
>   ... There are no constraints on the contents of the allocated storage on return from the
>   allocation function. The order, contiguity, and **initial value** of storage allocated by successive calls to an
>   allocation function **are unspecified**.
>
> **8.5 Initializers [dcl.init]**
>   7 To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>   — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the
>   initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>   — if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
>   — otherwise, no initialization is performed.

If you provide an explicit initializer, any variable will have a known value.

If you don't provide an explicit initializer for a POD type, it depends on the storage class. Static or thread variables will be zero initialized, whereas automatic or dynamically allocated variables are not.

If you have a compound type, the same rules apply. If you have don't have an explicit initializer, through a (default) constructor or otherwise, the initial value of fundamental types depends on the storage class.

Finally, memory allocated through `malloc` will be uninitialized, whereas `calloc` memory will be zero initialized.

Comment: Except if I provide a no-argument constructor for a class, it's initialized using that constructor. So this is incomplete enough to be misleading. And I know that sometimes automatically generated default constructors will initialize things too, but I don't know under which circumstances that happens.

Comment: @Omnifarious This is covered under `8.5 Initiailizers`. And the question is about POD types, not class types.