# `x ? 1 : 0` became 40, undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I wrote this code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <queue>

class Obj {
    bool x;
public:
    Obj(): x(true) {}
    Obj(Obj&& o) {
        o.x = false;
    }
    ~Obj() {
        if(x) {
            std::puts("Here");
            std::printf("%d\n", x ? 1 : 0);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    std::queue<Obj> q;
    q.push(Obj());
    q.pop();
}
```

With optimization enabled, I got a confusing result:

```
Here
40
```

And the number can be `160`, `24`, `96` or `104` by executing the program in different ways. On [Ideone](http://ideone.com/dIooX3) nothing is printed.

It must have been an undefined behavior. But I can't figure out what's wrong. **Can you point out my mistake?**

Note: My compiler is GCC 4.8.1, and my operating system is Windows 7.

Comment: Something weird with printf. Try using std::cout and see what you get.

Comment: @snowandotherjoys Unfortunately, still 40.

Comment: try a clean build? almost seem like compiler error

Comment: With your code I do not get any output at all

Comment: @johnchen902, out of interest, what, if any, optimisation switches where used with this sample?

Comment: @Niall I've tried `-O1` `-O2` `-O3` and `-Os`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't initialize `this->x` in your move constructor. I'm pretty sure conditionals on uninitialized variables are undefined behaviour.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <queue>

class Obj {
    bool x;
public:
    Obj(): x(true) {}
    Obj(Obj&& o) : x(true) { // Hi!
        o.x = false;
    }
    ~Obj() {
        if(x) {
            std::puts("Here");
            std::printf("%d\n", x ? 1 : 0);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    std::queue<Obj> q;
    q.push(Obj());
    q.pop();
}
```

The above works as expected (prints "Here 1").

Comment: Compiles and prints "Here 1" -- nice job!

Comment: Granted, the uninitialised variable will create randomness in the output, but isn't the `x` being evaluated in a boolean context, so the output should always be `0` or `1`. Where could the `40` have originally come from?

Comment: @johnchen902 embrace static analyzers + compiler warnings

Comment: @Niall no, member variables are not default-initialized to anything. if not initialized it truly has an undefined value. GCC will pick up on this in a heartbeat.

Comment: @Niall think of undefined behaviour as "all hell breaks loose". There _is_ no reason. The only thing left is _insanity_ (muhahahahaha!).

Comment: @snowandotherjoys, correct, they are not default initialised. `x` is never output, only `1` or `0` is. Where would the `40` have come from?

Comment: @Niall I don't know what's in the memory location pointed to by `x`. Maybe 40 was in there or something else that the compiler interpreted weirdly. You can use your imagination.

Comment: @Niall My guess is that compiler optimized it to `printf("%d", x)` as `x` *should* be `0` or `1`.

Comment: @snowandotherjoys I reckon he's asking about how the result of `x ? 0 : 1` could be anything other than 0 or 1. The answer is, undefined behaviour makes _anything_ possible if the compiler sees it as an optimization. I think johnchen902 got it.

Comment: @johnchen902 I think you are on to it. The evaluation is probably optimised away. Is this an incorrect optimisation then? The result of `x ? 0 : 1` should be either `1` or `0` and `1` and `0` are `int` and `x` is a `bool`, i.e. the outcome of `x ? 0 : 1` should be an `int` not a bool and not the value of `x`?

Comment: @Niall No. I meant something like `static_cast<int>(*reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x))`, in the assembly level.

Comment: @Niall `int` 0 and 1 are just an (implicit) cast away from a bool. I even thik that the cast itself is a no-op. So, if the compiler assumes `bool`s are correctly set (which is its right thanks to UB), it can completely optimize away the `?:`.

Comment: What happens is that compiler translates `x ? 1 : 0` into `x`, because a `bool` is just an integer that has the value `1` or `0` (`true` or `false`). Since that in turn means that the `x ? 1 : 0` is completely meaningless, it just removes the `? 1 : 0` , and prints whatever is in `x` - since `x` takes up at least a byte, you get some random garbage when `x` is not initialized.

Comment: @Quentin The cast needs to clean out 3 bytes, as `int` is 4 bytes (on my machine).

Comment: @Quentin, thanks for the note on the implicit casts. Given the context of the check and the cast involved, this optimisation makes much more sense.

Comment: Yes, using an indeterminate value is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415661/has-c-standard-changed-with-respect-to-the-use-of-indeterminate-values-and-und) it has always been explicit in C but was not in C++ until recently.