# Why is GCC tricked into allowing undefined behavior simply by putting it in a loop?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, compiler-warnings, undefined-behavior

The following is nonsensical yet compiles cleanly with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Winit-self` (I tested GCC 4.7.2 and 4.9.0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  for (int ii = 0; ii < 1; ++ii)
  {
    const std::string& str = str; // !!
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The line marked `!!` results in undefined behavior, yet is not diagnosed by GCC.  However, commenting out the `for` line makes GCC complain:

```
error: ‘str’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]
```

I would like to know: why is GCC so easily fooled here?  When the code is not in a loop, GCC knows that it is wrong.  But put the same code in a simple loop and GCC doesn't understand anymore.  This bothers me because we rely quite a lot on the compiler to notify us when we make silly mistakes in C++, yet it fails for a seemingly trivial case.

Bonus trivia:

- If you change `std::string` to `int` **and** turn on optimization, GCC will diagnose the error even with the loop.
- If you build the broken code with `-O3`, GCC literally calls the ostream insert function with a null pointer for the string argument.  If you thought you were safe from null references if you didn't do any unsafe casting, think again.

I have filed a GCC bug for this: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63203 - I'd still like to get a better understanding here of what went wrong and how it may impact the reliability of similar diagnostics.

Comment: Welp, +1 to clang: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8bde7751f3c2c0c

Comment: Perhaps you should fill a bug report on [GCC Bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla) ...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: absolutely.  The question here is a higher-level one: how/why should GCC be so easily tricked into accepting code it knows is wrong?  I'd like to better understand this; it took me a while to build the right test case for this because the first few I tried didn't fool GCC--I was shocked that a simple loop would defeat the warning.  Understanding why such things happen might help in trying to make sure our code isn't broken (previously I would have assumed I did not need to check for self-init of references, now I know I do need to).

Comment: File a bug. Complaining about GCC bugs here is not particularly productive.

Comment: In some ways a duplicate of my question... http://stackoverflow.com/q/25151508/541686

Comment: @n.m.: I have, and linked it in my post (as an edit, but well before your comment).  I am not complaining about the GCC bug here at all, but trying to understand how this sort of thing occurs within a modern compiler.

Comment: Again: it's a bug. Why bugs happen in GCC in unexpected places? Because GCC is a huge an complex beast, that's why. You think this is so simple and easy case this area should be bug-free? Volunteer to maintain it.

Comment: [dcl.ref]#5 "A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or function". Also I think it is UB to use the name of a reference before it has been bound although I can't find the relevant text right now

Comment: By the way it's [bug 18501](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18501), from 2004.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Does the fact that it's a reference actually matter? For example, is `Foo foo(&foo);` valid since `Foo` is not a reference?

Comment: @Mehrdad Your example isn’t invalid in itself though.

Comment: @LucDanton: Oh I didn't realize that, I thought it was...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I'd still like to get a better understanding here of what went wrong and how it may impact the reliability of similar diagnostics.

Unlike Clang, GCC doesn't have logic to detect self-initialized references, so getting a warning here relies on the code for detecting use of uninitialized variables, which is quite temperamental and unreliable (see [Better Uninitialized Warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Better_Uninitialized_Warnings) for discussion).

With an `int` the compiler can figure out that you write an uninitialized `int` to the stream, but with a `std::string` there are apparently too many layers of abstraction between an expression of type `std::string` and getting the `const char*` it contains, and GCC fails to detect the problem.

e.g. GCC does give a warning for a simpler example with less code between the declaration and use of the variable, as long as you enable some optimization:

```
extern "C" int printf(const char*, ...);

struct string {
  string() : data(99) { }
  int data;
  void print() const { printf("%d\n", data); }
};

int main()
{
  for (int ii = 0; ii < 1; ++ii)
  {
    const string& str = str; // !!
    str.print();
  }
}

d.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
d.cc:6:43: warning: ‘str’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   void print() const { printf("%d\n", data); }
                                           ^
d.cc:13:19: note: ‘str’ was declared here
     const string& str = str; // !!
                   ^
```

I suspect this kind of missing diagnostic is only likely to affect a handful of diagnostics which rely on heuristics to detect problems. These would be the ones that give a warning of the form "*may* be used uninitialized" or "*may* violate strict aliasing rules", and probably the "array subscript is above array bounds" warning. Those warnings are not 100% accurate and "complicated" logic like loops(!) can cause the compiler to give up trying to analyse the code and fail to give a diagnostic.

IMHO the solution would be to add checking for self-initialized references at the point of initialization, and not rely on detecting it is uninitialized later when it gets used.

Answer (score 1):

You claim it's undefined behavior, but when I compile the two cases to assembly, I definitely see the function-scoped variable not being initialized on the stack, and the block-scoped variable getting set to NULL.

That's as much of an answer as you're getting from me.   I downloaded the C++ spec to definitively settle this, but fell into a Lovecraftian-type fugue when I gazed upon it, to preserve my fragile sanity...

I strongly suspect the block-scoped case is not actually undefined.

Comment: Using a null reference is undefined behavior.  Which of the two lines the UB occurs on may be up for debate, but I think it's clearly UB (and it does segfault).

Comment: Sorry, I meant non-initialized.  (Hence, no -Werror-uninitialized warning.)

Comment: Well I never claimed anything about non-initialization.  GCC did, when I commented out the loop.  Whether it says non-initialized or initialized-with-self in the diagnostic doesn't matter to me, I just expect a diagnostic!

Comment: Hey, look there's evidently a -Winit-self that is separate from -Wall because of "the common but questionable practice of initializing auto storage class variables with themselves to supress warnings"

Spoiler:  enabling it doesn't cause your test case to emit a warning. =p

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18016

Fixed in 4.7.0 my foot.   Go ahead and submit, I think...

Comment: yes, I used `-Winit-self` in the question as you can see.  And you're right, it doesn't help.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I dont' see any null references

Comment: @MattMcNabb: well that's what GCC emits when you compile with optimization: the ostream insert operator is called with a constant `0` instead of a pointer to a string.  So while the code doesn't intentionally build a null reference per se, GCC emits code as if it did.

Comment: @BadZen It *is* fixed (at least in 4.8 on): the problematic testcase in that report does produce warnings as expected. Seeing as the OP’s case involves no member variable, the relevance of the report you’ve found is questionable.

Comment: As @LucDanton says, PR18016 is unrelated, it is about self-initialized member variables, which is questionable but not undefined behaviour, so deserves a warning. Self-initialized references are ill-formed and should be an error, always, but 18016 has nothing to do with references.

Comment: (Actually clang and EDG only give a warning for self-initialized references, which matches the OP's statement that it's UB not ill-formed, but it's still nothing to do with 18016 :-)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I wish self-initialization of references were ill-formed, but I have not found anything to suggest it is.  I am now wondering if this is something to suggest to the C++ committee for C++17 or so.  It would seem there is no possible valid use of this, but I am prepared for some to come out of the woodwork (perhaps SFINAE).

Comment: SFINAE should go away in favour of concepts in C++17 anyway, so that isn't a good reason. Someone might have a reason, but I'd say it's worth proposing it to WG21. Maybe the Undefined Behaviour study group would be interested.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I have written to ub@isocpp here: http://www.open-std.org/pipermail/ub/ (it's pending moderator approval).  Thank you.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: ...and my posting to the UB mailing list was rejected by the moderators.  There have been no messages accepted for roughly three months--maybe the UB group is no longer?  Anyway, if you have the right ears listening you're more than welcome to steal this proposal.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, the SG12 chair tells me you need to subscribe to the list before posting, the list is active.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: my message was accepted this time; the thread is here for posterity: http://www.open-std.org/pipermail/ub/2014-September/000506.html and some discussion has begun already.  Thanks again.