# Simple way to return an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, pass-by-reference

I am trying to use the following `id` function in C++. I would have assumed that I can simply do;

```
typedef int v3[3];

v3 & id( v3 & in )
{
  in[0] = in[1] = in[2] = 1;
  return in;
}

int main()
{
  v3 & v = id( v );
  return 0;
}
```

However this leads to a segfault with `g++` (this is not clear to me). Since I can do the following with scalar-type:

```
int & zero( int & in )
{
  in = 0;
  return in;
}

int main()
{
  int i = zero( i );
  return 0;
}
```

How can I use `id` with a single line of code ? I'd like to avoid an ugly solution such as:

```
int main()
{
  v3 v;
  v3 & w = id( v );
}
```

Of course I do not want to use `std::vector` or `std::array` (c++11). So I am really interested why my naive solution is actually `undefined behavior`.

EDIT: `std::vector` will require dynamic allocation which in my case should be avoid (I need to manipulation thousands of `vr3`). I cannot use `std::array` since I am required to stick to `c++03`. Obviously one could not guess my requirements.

Comment: You allocate storage for a reference named `v`. What does it point to and where do you write when you do `v[0] = v[1] = v[2] = 1;`!?

Comment: If you're interested in the "Is this undefined behavior?" and "Why does the compiler compile it?" aspects, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25717740/why-is-gcc-tricked-into-allowing-undefined-behavior-simply-by-putting-it-in-a-lo

Comment: I am really interested, what could be a good reason to not use `std::vector<>` or `std::array<>`. It must be so obvious to you, that you tell us, that "of course" you don't want to use them. Please be a bit more elaborate on this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am really interested why my naive solution is actually undefined behavior.

It's UB because: You initialize the reference `v` with the return value of `id`, and `id` returns the reference that is it's parameter. The parameter passed to `id` is `v`, so therefore you initialize `v` with it's uninitialized self, without ever allocating an object to refer to.

> How can I use id with a single line of code ?

Well, you could simply type two statements on one line (and get rid of the redundant assignment):

```
v3 v; id(v);
```

But, it would be simpler to:

```
v3 v{1, 1, 1};
```

> I need to return an array.

If you read [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) carefully, you'll find out that you're out of luck. Arrays can not be returned or passed as parameters. What you can do is use a wrapper class that holds the array inside. But there is no need to implement it yourself because the standard library already provides one: `std::array`.

> Of course I do not want to use std::vector or std::array

You've painted yourself into a corner with your conflicting wants. You'll need to reimplement `std::array` yourself then. I don't recommend you do that.

Comment: thanks for the clear explanations ! At least I understand my mistake now.

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
v3 & v = id( v );
```

And this:

```
int i = zero( i );
```

Are nonsense, because you cannot use something in its own initializer.  Some compilers will warn you about this, but some won't.

You could make a macro:

```
#define V3_UNIT {1,1,1}
```

Now you can do:

```
v3 v = V3_UNIT;
```

`PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` is one common example of this technique in the wild.

Comment: You are lucky you got a warning. This would cause NULL reference exception at run time since v is not initialized.

Comment: @FigaroCat: What is a "NULL reference exception" in C++?

Comment: Actually you *can* use something in it's own initializer - provided you are using it to initialize a reference or pointer.  You can't use the *value*.

Comment: @John Zwinck: Not related to the language. CPU exception. (On MIPS it TLBL exception)

Comment: @FigaroCat you are still relatively *lucky* if you get a *CPU exception*. That's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
#include <array>

using v3 = std::array<int, 3>;

v3 id()
{
  return {{ 1, 1, 1 }};
}

int main()
{
  v3 v = id();
}
```

Comment: As said in my post, I cannot use `std::array` (or a solution based on struct return). I need to return an array.

Comment: @malat, but you aren't returning an array, you are returning a reference to an array.

Comment: @malat It's either `std::array` or `std::vector` (which should be the preferred solution before C++11), or your "ugly" solution. That's the choices you have (unless you want to allocate memory dynamically, which I really don't recommend).

Comment: @malat you can use `std::array<>` and call `std::array<>::data()`, whenever you have to pass on a C array to legacy code.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that in your sample `main` in the v case you don't have a `v3` *anywhere*.  You only have references to `v3`s, and there is nothing for them to refer to.

You get away with it in the `int` case because you have a real genuine `int` to refer to.  (But it may well be undefined behaviour - it is certainly very dodgy.)

Answer (score 1):

This code is undefined behaviour:

```
v3 & v = id( v );
```

under clang you will get warning:

> warning: reference 'v' is not yet bound to a value when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]

---

[edit]

Actually I am not 100% sure if self assignment of reference is UB or ill-formed code, I have found interesting discussions on this topic:

[Why is GCC tricked into allowing undefined behavior simply by putting it in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25717740/why-is-gcc-tricked-into-allowing-undefined-behavior-simply-by-putting-it-in-a-lo)
http://www.open-std.org/pipermail/ub/2014-September/000506.html

which suggests that it should be rather ill-formed - but it looks like the discussion is in progress. Most common comment on such code is `nonsense` but I suppose only due to the fact that its hard to find appropiate part of standard on this.

Comment: so UB is equivalent to having a warning with `clang` ? could you be more specific.

Comment: @malat I have updated my answer. Warning not always indicate UB.

Answer (score 0):

You  may initial values in braces {}.
Like: `in = {1,1,1};`