# Is a local scoped variable initialized to an undetermined value, or un-initialized?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Pedantically speaking, is `x` initialized in the following code or not?

```
int main()
{
    int x;
}
```

There are some paragraphs about it in **8.5 Initializers [dcl.init]** (for C++11) but not backed by any examples.

Comment: Short answer, no. Long answer, nope.

Comment: It is default-initialized. Which means that no initialization is performed (for `int`).

Comment: Thus it stays indeterminate, so reading it (as it is auto-storage-class) is UB.

Answer (score 5):

It is formally *default-initialized*, which means for `int`s, that no initialization is performed.

[dcl.init]/12 (N3797)

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized; if no initialization is performed, an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value

[dcl.init]/7

> To *default-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type, the default
>     constructor for `T` is called [...];
> - if `T` is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
> - **otherwise, no initialization is performed**.

Comment: So, it is initialized, but that action consists of "no initialization is performed".  Either that, or it is default-initialized, but default-initialized is not a kind of initialized in this case.  Or, the term "initialized" has no formal meaning in the standard, while "default-initialized" does as does "initializaion is performed".  Gah.

Comment: @Yakk Exactly. Reminds me of complete types that cannot be completed.

Comment: @Yakk: It stays indeterminate is thus factually correct and the standard conformant wording for its state. So, using it if it's auto-storage-class is UB according to 4.1 lvalue-to-rvalue-conversion [conv.lval].

Comment: @Deduplicator thankfully [in C++14](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801) we don't need to rely on the l-to-r conversion to know this undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't. According to standard, `x` is *default-initialized* ([dcl.init]/6):

> To *default-initialize* an object of type T means:
>
> — if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type [...]
>
> — if `T` is an array type [...]
>
> — **otherwise, no initialization was performed**.

`x` is therefore uninitialized since no initialization is performed. 
Hence the object has indeterminate value ([dcl.init]/11):

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is
> default-initialized; **if no initialization is performed, an object
> with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value**.

Moreover, if we were to access it's stored, indeterminate value - in other words, perform an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on it - we would induce undefined behavior ([conv.lval]/1]):

> If the object to which the glvalue refers is [..], **or if the object
> is uninitialized, a program that necessitates this conversion has
> undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand it is that the place in memory for the variable x is reserved, but not set to a value (un-initialized). Because it is un-initialized, any old values there will be considered as 'garbage' int.