# Is passing an uninitialised variable in a function parameter list well-defined?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I have some code which essentially boils down to the following:

```
void bar(bool b, double f)
{
    if (b){
        double g = f;
    }
}

void foo()
{
    double f;
    bool b = false;
    bar(b, f);
}
```

Is there any undefined behaviour here? I suspect there may be since I'm taking a value copy of the uninitialised `double` when passing `f` to `bar`. That said, I'm not making use of the passed `double` though since the `if` block will not run.

Furthermore, would everything be fine if I were to pass the `double` by reference:

```
void bar(bool b, double& f)
```

Then I'm not "using" an uninitialised variable but am simply referring to it.

Comment: You don't have undefined behavior until you try to access the variable, and since that's done when passing it by value to the function you have undefined behavior in the call. If you instead pass by reference, then you have undefined behavior in the function when you then access the value of the reference.

Comment: "using a unitialized value is by itself not undefined behavior, but the value is simply indeterminate." (From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11965368/96780))

Comment: @DanielDaranas *If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), **the behavior is undefined.*** And that answer is referring to C btw.

Comment: @DanielDaranas Trap representation was introduced by C99, I'm unsure if it applies to C++.

Comment: @2501 Oops, I shouldn't have quoted an answer which refers to a different programming language. You're right - I just leave my previous comment for completeness.

Comment: @DanielDaranas I'm fairly confident C++ says the same.

Comment: @2501 And I'm even more confident that C++ doesn't. The suggestion to update the C++ standard to refer to trap representations resulted in a different update, with different words that have a different meaning. Particularly, in C++, reading uninitialised variables is *never* allowed for any type that is not an unsigned character type, regardless of whether the type in C would have trap representations. See [#616](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#616). Even if a type *is* an unsigned character type, it's not unconditionally allowed, but only in some cases.

Comment: @hvd So you are saying it is undefined( that was my point ).

Comment: @2501 Yes, and I'm saying that C++ follows different rules than C, that C++ is more strict about it.

Comment: It becomes undefined behavior [when a value is produced by an evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801), so the first case is undefined the second case is fine until unless you use `f` in an indeterminate state.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the behaviour is undefined. You *are* taking a value copy of the uninitialised `double` when passing it in the function parameter list.

Passing by reference *is* well-defined since all you're doing is binding that reference to that `double`. Of course, the behaviour of accessing that reference *would* be undefined.

N4140:

[dcl.init]

> `12` ...  If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the
>   behavior is undefined except in the following cases:

*(Irrelevant text omitted, pertaining to unsigned narrow character types)*