# Vector of object containing uninitialized value

Tags: c++, initialization, stdvector, undefined-behavior

Does this code cause undefined behaviour:

```
#include <vector>

struct S
{
    S() {}

    int x;
};

int main()
{
     std::vector<S> vec(5, S());
}
```

Since `S()` default-initializes an automatic object, its contents are not zeroed first, so `x` would be indeterminate. Then the object containing indeterminate value is copied to each vector location.

**Motivation:** We might expect this to behave the same as `std::vector<S> vec(5);` which is not UB (since C++11), so this would be an easy mistake to make by accident.

As referred to by Praetorian in comments, prior to C++11 `std::vector<S> vec(5);` was free to either do 5 default-initializations, or to use the copy-constructor for some or all of the items.

Comment: [dcl.init]/p12 "If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the behavior is undefined except in the
following cases: [a few bullets related to unsigned narrow character types]". So, yes, it's UB.

Comment: Why would you think it is not undefined behavior?

Comment: @TC, I am not seeing that in the Draft Standard N3337. Just curious, which document has those lines?

Comment: @RSahu it is in the C++14 standard, I covered this in [Has C++ standard changed with respect to the use of indeterminate values and undefined behavior in C++14?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801), previously we had to rely on the underspecified lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to prove UB.

Comment: @MattMcNabb ok, your comment makes this a more interesting question and a good one, please edit that into your question.

Comment: @MattMcNabb No, that is not UB because no copies are made in that case. `vector<S> vec(5);` will default construct 5 separate instances (IIRC this change was made in C++11 to allow `vector` to contain move only types). If you subsequently cause copies of those to be made, then the same rules as explained above apply.

Answer (score 4):

So taking into account the following comment by the OP:

> vector vec(5); is not UB (is it?) and we tend to think that (5) and
>   (5, S()) ought to do the same thing. I could see this mistake being
>   made by accident quite easily.

The question boils down to if:

```
vector<S> vec(5);
```

is well defined then why is:

```
std::vector<S> vec(5, S());
```

undefined behavior?

If we go to the cppreference section of [std::vector::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) we can see in the first case it (*since C++11*) (*emphasis mine*):

> Constructs the container with count default-inserted instances of T.
>   **No copies are made**.

while in the second case:

> Constructs the container with **count copies** of elements with value
>   value.

The first case will default construct the elements and no copies are made while in the second case copies will be made and therefore we end up copying `x` to each element. Since the default constructor of `S` does not initialize `x`, it will have an *indeterminate value* and therefore we have undefined behavior since producing an *indeterminate value* invokes undefined behavior.

Since C++14 section `8.5` paragraph `12` says:

> If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the behavior
>   is undefined except in the following cases

with some exceptions in the case of *unsigned char* which does not apply in this case.

We know that `x` has an indeterminate value from the same paragraph which says:

> When storage for an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration
>   is obtained, the object has an indeterminate value, and if no
>   initialization is performed for the object, that object retains an
>   indeterminate value until that value is replaced

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** Yes, this is Undefined Behavior.

---

In your code you value-initialize a temporary:

```c++
std::vector<S> vec(5, S());
//                    ^^^
```

From §8.5/10:

> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., `()`, shall be value-initialized.

The definition for value-initialization is:

> **§8.5/8**
>
> To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> > — if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with either no default constructor (12.1) or a default constructor that is user-provided or deleted, then the object is default-initialized;
> >
> > — [..]

Value-initialization does not include zero-initialization in this case because `S` has a user-declared default-constructor. So it is default-constructed.

> **§8.5/7**
>
> To default-initialize an object of type `T` means:
>
> > — **If `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated (13.3.1.3), and the best one for the initializer `()` is chosen through overload resolution (13.3). The constructor thus selected is called, with an empty argument list, to initialize the object.**
> >
> > — If T is an array type, each element is default-initialized.
> >
> > — Otherwise, no initialization is performed.

Since your default-constructor doesn't explicitly initialize `x`, it keep it's uninitialized garbage value. The default copy-constructor initializes the other elements with these values which is UB.

> **§8.5/12**
>
> If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the behavior is undefined