# Is it legal to increment non-initialized variable?

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
 int i;
 i++; // 1
}
```

Can I be sure that I always get the value "1" after using increment? Because I often hear that a variable can contain anything before initializing. So it's illegal? Or increment always starts from "0" if the variable is a non-initialized?

Comment: It is undefined behaviour.

Comment: It's illegal, since for incrementing, you need to first read the value of the variable (which is UB).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not necessarily undefined behaviour, because it depends very much upon the version of the language — things are much clearer in C++14, however. Either way though, there are no guarantees you will get the value 1.

- `int i;` in this context declares `i` with *automatic* storage duration, and with default initialization. For `int`, default initialization leaves the variable with *indeterminate* value.
- In C, *indeterminate value* is defined in the standard: `i` will have some value, or a trap representation.
- The increment operation adds one to the value of `i`, which was indeterminate. If it happened to be a trap representation, this could raise a signal. (On your typical PC hardware and C or C++ compiler, there won't be any trap representations for `int`.)
- Until the C++14 draft, C++ left open what was meant by *indeterminate*; it was used, but not defined. Once might assume that it meant the same thing as in the C standard, but frankly there are no guarantees here.
- With C++14, this has been nailed down, and except for a limited number of operations on narrow characters, doing anything with indeterminate values leads to undefined behaviour.

In short: if it were C, it's not undefined behaviour, but no promises that it will be 1; if it were pre-C++14 C++, it's not properly specified in the standard, but at the very least, there are no promises that it will be 1; and in C++14 it is specified that this is undefined behaviour.

There's an [interesting and informative discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415661/has-c-standard-changed-with-respect-to-the-use-of-indeterminate-values-and-und) of what indeterminate means in C++ on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 7):

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized. When storage for an object
>   with automatic or dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an indeterminate value, and if
>   no initialization is performed for the object, that object retains an indeterminate value until that value is
>   replaced

Default-initialization for integers is a no-op, meaning no initialization is performed. That means `i` in your example has an indeterminate value. Using the object as if it had a value results in undefined behavior:

> If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the behavior is undefined [..]

Answer (score 4):

no it will have undefined behaviour.

i++ doesn't start from 0, it simply increment by one based on the previous value, in this case i has indeterminate value.

see t[his question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c) for more detail

Comment: Thanks for the link! I was unaware of the could-have-been-register caveat for undefined behaviour in C.

Answer (score 1):

Only global variables are zero initialized. This one is defined inside function and it is not static so it is local. It means `i` contains random garbage after it is created.

Answer (score 1):

No practical use in the real world. This will give you undefined behaviour. Each time you will get a different value.