# Is using compound assignment operator (+=, ...) on uninitialized variable NOT a UB in C++?

Tags: c++, initialization, undefined-behavior

I am trying to create a simple tool to detect the use of uninitialized variables based on Clang AST. What I know is that the thing actually causes UB with uninit variables is an lvalue to rvalue cast that happens implicitly.

Now what I noticed while examining the AST of a basic example program is that all compound assignment operators **do not** cause any such cast node to appear! Does this imply that **no UB** takes place?

```
int a;
int b = 10;
b += a; // this line is obviously UB...
a += b; // ... but is this one ok?

// Note: no ImplicitCastExpr of LvalueToRvalue type in AST !
```

That is also true for postfix / prefix increment / decrement operators (in particular, I have absolutely no clue how postfix operators save the '*value*' of the variable without copying).

I managed to find some info about increment operators ([Is it legal to increment non-initialized variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551951/is-it-legal-to-increment-non-initialized-variable) - only one reference, unfortunately), but now struggle with comp. assignments. If possible, I'd love to know in particular what happens to increment as well.

Comment: `int a; a += b;` is definitely UB.

Comment: *"the thing actually causes UB with uninit variables is an lvalue to rvalue cast that happens implicitly"* can you elaborate?

Comment: Further, "I have absolutely no clue how postfix operators save the 'value' of the variable without copying" - they don't; thus the point of why postfix is expensive and should only be used when you actually *need* the value-prior in the first place.

Comment: If you think of the `+=` operator as simply being defined as `int &operator+=(int &l, int r) { return l = l + r }`, I think it becomes clear. The evaluation of `l` is simply hidden inside "library code."

Comment: Well, looks like Clang AST lies from time to time...

Comment: That's assuming that you are interpreting the AST correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is using compound assignment operator (+=, …) on uninitialized variable NOT a UB in C++?

No, it **is** UB (except for in cases where standard says it's not).

Standard quotes (from latest draft):

> [expr.ass] The behavior of an expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = E1 op E2 except that **E1 is evaluated** only once.

So, we know that left hand operand is evaluated. And we also know that the value is used in the operation.

> [basic.indet] If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, **the behavior is undefined** ...

There you have it.