# How to add every element in a matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix

I am trying too add every element in a int matrix so I can check if the player or computer wins.

```
bool WinCondition(int Grid[10][10])
{
    int SumOfShips;
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
        {
            SumOfShips += Grid[a][b] ;
            if (SumOfShips == 30) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

However "+=" isn't working for me neither is . . . = Grid[a][b] + SumOfShips, I am getting the error "unititialized local variable 'SumOfShips' used"

Comment: Local variables are never initialized unless you explicitly do it. Uninitialized local variables will have an *indeterminate* value, and using such values in C++ leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `int SumOfShips = 0;` or some initial value, which makes sense in the context.

The reason being, that `SumOfShips`, when not initialized holds an arbitrary (indeterminate) value given the randomly assigned memory location.

Further, the uninitialized value is regarded as being 'indeterminate', check here for a more  [thorough explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551951/is-it-legal-to-increment-non-initialized-variable).

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, the variable `SumOfShips` is used without being initialized.

Initialize that like this:

```
int SumOfShips = 0;
```

instead of:

```
int SumOfShips;
```