# different clang and gcc behavior with pointers

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang

For example, we have the following simple code:

```
#include "stdio.h"   

int main() {   
  int* pointer_to_check;
  printf("%x\n", pointer_to_check);
  return 0;
}
```

With gcc, we will get zero at output (as for me, normal behavior, because pointer isn't associated with memory), but clang gives us a real address, which can be accessed without "segmentation fault".

I have two questions:

1. What is the normal behavior according to the C standard (and C++)?
2. Why does this happen?

Comment: In C++ using an [indeterminate value is undefined behavor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801) and so the behavior is unpredictable and can vary. It is also undefined behavior in [C as well](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/03/13/indeterminate-undefined).

Comment: Cool Guy has the only correct answer.  Just wanted to add that your compiler will report this kind of behavior.  Try compiling with `-Wall` for either compiler...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pointer_to_check` to check is uninitialized. It points to some "random" location.

Accessing uninitialized variables leads to [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which means that anything can happen.

Also, pointers should be printed using the `%p` format specifier.

---

> with gcc code, we will get zero at output

Anything can be the output. It is Undefined. You shouldn't rely on this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

This is undefined behaviour.

Pointers are not initialized when you declare them, so they could point anywhere. `0`, `0xDEADBEEF` or anything else are "valid" representations.

If you want the pointer to be initialized to null, do it explicitly:

```
int* pointer_to_check = nullptr;
```

Comment: It could be even ``0xCAFEBABE`` ;)