# Does C++ initialize integers to zero automatically?

Tags: c++, coverity

I've noticed several Coverity (static-analysis tool) errors of type 'Uninitialized scalar variable' that are high impact. A lot of them are just ints that don't get initialized.

Would initializing them to zero be any different than what C++ does by default?

Comment: I edited to refocus on C++ for this question. I largely work in a C# code-base, but these issues are all in C++ code, sorry about the lack of clarity earlier.

Comment: Well, int's are value types in both c++ and C#, they use X bytes of ram, and all 0 bits, they are 0.  So whether you initialize them or not, in memory they are still 0.

Comment: Whether they are zero initialized or not depends on their storage type (static or automatic) and on how they are initialized. It might be easier to answer if you post a complete code sample.

Comment: I'm unable to post any code samples (production code, NDAs, IP, etc.) -- otherwise I would. A lot of my struggle is asking myself, "Is there a safe/good default value to set the int to?". What happens if it's set to 0? Sometimes I've found there is no good default case or maybe it will very-very-rarely go down a path where it doesn't get set even though it wasn't initialized. Then it's just not worth initializing it to a value that might not be a good default. That said, I didn't want this question to go down a design path to make sure it's a clear and concise question.

Comment: @PerryCampbell The problem is that reading from an uninitialized variable is undefined behaviour. So as long as you set the value to something before reading, you're fine.

Comment: Note using a variable with [indeterminate value is undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Does C++ initialize integers to zero automatically?

For automatic variables:

Some compilers might do it but the standard does not require it. A conforming implementation could leave them to be uninitialized garbage values.

For `static` variables:

They must be initialized to zero unless explicitly initialized otherwise.

Comment: "Some compilers might do it." Are you sure? Clang, gcc, and MSVC will all not initialize scalars in Release builds.

Comment: MSVC does, I believe. It may be only in Debug builds (not sure), but that still counts.

Comment: In my opinion, compilers should never initialize a variable automatically, especially if it changes from one build to another.
That would mean that you could have bugs that don't appear in debug builds, which defeats the point

Comment: Yup, some versions of msvc do that in debug mode. You'll be tearing your hair out if you hit a bug because of this.

Comment: @KABoissonneault It doesn't matter, because reading from such an uninitialized variable is undefined behaviour anyway. So whether a sompiler initializes to 0 or not is irrelevant 'cause you're not allowed to look.

Comment: @celticminstrel I guess you're right because I don't see a point. I'm talking automatic storage, BTW.

Comment: @KABoissonneault It would be very useful for the compiler to initialize them in debug build. To some value that is highly unlikely to be what you want: as you point out, initializing them to 0 is generally anti-productive, but initializing them to 0xDEADBEAF, or something like that, is a good idea (and I think that's what modern MVS does).

Comment: @JamesKanze I should have specified "initialize to 0", but yes you are right

Answer (score 15):

C++ does not initialize integer variables to zero by default.

Some compilers may zero them out or fill with some default value *while compiling your project in debug mode*. In release mode that usually does not happen.

There is an exception with static variables, but by default it is safe to assume that anything unitialized holds a random value.

Beware of uninitialized variables. Finding this kind of bug is hard and can waste a lot of time. Usual symptoms: the program works fine in debug mode, but behaves strangely in release.

Comment: But what about this? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization It seems to say that in many cases ints are initialized to zero?

Comment: Yes, many cases, such as  `static int myint;` and  `int myint = int();` but not a plain old  `int myint;`  A plain old `int myint;`  is NOT initialised to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Objects declared in static storage duration are zero initialized before any other initialization takes place (including default initializations).

> To *default-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>   — if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for `T` is called (and the
>   initialization is ill-formed if `T` has no accessible default constructor);
>   — if `T` is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
>   — otherwise, no initialization is performed
>   <sub>C.11 §8.5¶6</sub>
>
> [ *Note*: Every object of static storage duration is zero-initialized at program startup before any other initialization
>   takes place. In some cases, additional initialization is done later. — *end note* ]
>   <sub>C.11 §8.5¶9</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

It depends how they are declared. If they are declared `static`, then yes, they are guaranteed to be zero-initialized. However, local variables in a function may not be zero-initialized. Nor are class member variables in most contexts (the exception being `static`).

Basically, if it's not `static`, you should assume it won't be initialized to 0. Since it's not initialized, it could have any value whatsoever.

Comment: If it isn't static, default initialization leaves it uninitialized, and you can't assume *anything*. You can't even read from it.

Comment: That's pretty much what I said, isn't it?

Comment: No, otherwise I wouldn't have commented.

Comment: I haven't said you can assume anything. The original poster was talking about initializing to 0, so I focused on that, but I haven't said anything that's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

> errors of type 'Uninitialized scalar variable' that are high impact

Yes, they are high impact because an uninitialized automatic variable has indeterminate value and [using an indeterminate value is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801) so these are serious bugs if you attempt to produce a value from them before initialization.

> Would initializing them to zero be any different than what C++ does by default?

Yes, for automatic scalar variables the C++ standard says they will have indeterminate value, the draft C++ standard from section `8.5` *[dcl.init]*:

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is
>   default-initialized. When storage for an object with automatic or
>   dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an indeterminate
>   value, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that
>   object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced
>   (5.17 [expr.ass])

A compiler may in debug mode initialize local variable, to aid in debugging, we can see that [MSVC can do this using /RTC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz.aspx):

> Initialization of local variables to a nonzero value. This helps
>   identify bugs that do not appear when running in debug mode.[...]