# Runtime error: load of value 127, which is not a valid value for type 'bool'

Tags: c++, g++, ubsan

I'm using g++ 4.9.2 on Debian 8, x86_64. I'm catching a Undefined Behavior sanitizer (UBsan) (`-fsanitize=undefined`) error:

```
algebra.cpp:206:8: runtime error: load of value 127,
    which is not a valid value for type 'bool'
```

The code is from the Crypto++ library. Here is the code at `algebra.cpp:206` (and some related code):

```
206   struct WindowSlider
207   {
208     WindowSlider(const Integer &expIn, bool fastNegate, unsigned int windowSizeIn=0)
209         : m_exp(expIn), m_windowModulus(Integer::One()), m_windowSize(windowSizeIn), m_windowBegin(0), m_fastNegate(fastNegate), m_firstTime(true), m_finished(false)
210     {
            ...
249         Integer m_exp, m_windowModulus;
250         unsigned int m_windowSize, m_windowBegin;
251         word32 m_expWindow;
252         bool m_fastNegate, m_negateNext, m_firstTime, m_finished;
253     };
```

Its called in a couple of places, like:

```
$ grep -I WindowSlider *
...
algebra.cpp:    std::vector<WindowSlider> exponents;
algebra.cpp:        exponents.push_back(WindowSlider(*expBegin++, InversionIsFast(), 0));
ecp.cpp:    std::vector<WindowSlider> exponents;
ecp.cpp:        exponents.push_back(WindowSlider(*expBegin++, InversionIsFast(), 5));
```

`InversionIsFast` is a `bool`, so that should not be a problem. But I added `!!InversionIsFast()` just in case and the issue persists.

**EDIT**: Here is a grep for `InversionIsFast`. It appears it is initialized.

```
$ grep -I InversionIsFast *
algebra.cpp:        exponents.push_back(WindowSlider(*expBegin++, !!InversionIsFast(), 0));
algebra.h:  virtual bool InversionIsFast() const {return false;}
ec2n.h: bool InversionIsFast() const {return true;}
ecp.cpp:        exponents.push_back(WindowSlider(*expBegin++, !!InversionIsFast(), 5));
ecp.h:  bool InversionIsFast() const {return true;}
```

I also initialized `m_negateNext` in the ctor.

What is the issue, and how do I clear it?

Comment: Does `InversionIsFast()` return a boolean expression or does it simply cast to a `bool`? If it's the latter, I would say change to the former. Would probably fix this error and is a better programming practice, IMO.

Comment: This blog [post](http://blog.llvm.org/2013/04/testing-libc-with-fsanitizeundefined.html) suggests it may be due to unintialized bool, see the comment at the end. Which from what I can tell seems to be the case with `m_negateNext`.

Comment: @Red Alert - I'll check on that. The code is C++03, so there should be no `constexpr`. Shakif - It tried that after I posted. No joy, same issue.

Comment: @jww By boolean expression, I mean something like `return num != 0;` rather than `return num;`, assuming `num` is an integer.

Comment: If reading `InversionIsFast` reads an uninitialized bool, running `!!InversionIsFast` doesn't make it any less uninitialized (reading uninitialized values is UB).

Comment: @RedAlert and  GManNickG - Good points. I added an audit of `InversionIsFast`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The blog post [Testing libc++ with -fsanitize=undefined](http://blog.llvm.org/2013/04/testing-libc-with-fsanitizeundefined.html) which also mentioned a similar error:

> runtime error: load of value 64, which is not a valid value for type
>   'bool'

suggests it may be due to uninitialized bool, see the comment at the end which says:

> I had not (in class) initialised the bool [...]

Which from what I can tell is the case with `m_negateNext` since it is not initialized in the constructor of `WindowSlider` while the rest of the member variables are.

An uninitialized bool will have indeterminate value and [using an indeterminate value is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801).

Comment: I think you were right. The makefile lacks dependencies, so a `make` did not rebuild all the required files. After a make clean, I cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQmdW.png)Don't put the bool int the function，because it is not initialized.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Include your code in the answer as text.