# Declaration in if statement weird behaviour (C++)

Tags: c++, clang++

I have following code:

```
int X = 1;
if (int X = X)
{
    printf("%d\n", X);
    if (int X = X)
    {
       printf("%d\n", X);
    }
}
```

My expectation is X should be 1, 1. However, the output is:

```
1818935350
32767
```

Anyone know what's going on here? Compiled with clang-800.0.42.1

**Edit:** I tried the following code with a bit tweak, and now it behaves as I expected.

```
int X = 1;
if (int Y = X)
{
    printf("%d\n", Y);
    if (int Z = X)
    {
        printf("%d\n", Z);
    }
}
```

One guess is when you use variable on RHS of a declaration inside if statement, it might not refer to the variable with the same name declared at parent scope, instead it's referring to the variable that's being defined...

Comment: get rid of the 'int' before the X in the if statement. Also if you want to make a comparison you need to use `==` not `=`. `=` sets the value of X. However, it's tough seeing what you're trying to accomplish here. Maybe give some desired input and output

Comment: @bpgeck That's not what I intend to do. I want to check the behaviour when you use declaration inside if statement.

Comment: @Avi Berger Yeah I know, but believe or not. I got a problem that's kind of similar to this. I need some macro that will be expanded to the if statements, and I want them to automatically refer to the one with the same name in parent scope ... Seems that's not possible.

Comment: See [Has C++ standard changed with respect to the use of indeterminate values and undefined behavior in C++14?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801) for a more detailed explanation of the issue.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Nice reference, didn't know that before :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `int X = X`, both X's refer to the same `int`. That is, the one you are declaring right there in that line. So you are initializing `X` with itself, which is undefined behavior, since it was (of course) not already initialized. The `X` that you initialized with 1 is never printed in your code, since it is declared in a parent scope and shadowed by the ones in the inner scopes.

Comment: I'm surprised the compiler allows this.

Comment: @benjamin Lindley. See my edit, it's same with your guess.

Comment: @A. Stone: It's not a guess.

Comment: @A.Stone - your edit is of no surprise. The real issue pointed out here is the scope of the variable.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley. Sorry...

Comment: @A.Stone: No worries. Hope that statement didn't come off as arrogant. Just confident.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley :)

Comment: @A.Stone I just check doing `A a = a;` prevent call to default constructor instead copy constructor is called.

Answer (score 0):

In C, this `if (int X = X)` is plain wrong because the `if` statement expects a control expression - but NOT a declaration.

> 6.8.4.1 The if statement
>
> The controlling expression of an if statement shall have scalar type.

I'm not sure about `clang`, but `gcc` gives this code an obvious error (not a warning) even without any compiler flag (ie without  `-Wall -Wextra`)

> error: expected expression before ‘int’

Comment: Maybe it's C++ only, can you try clang++ or g++?

Comment: @A.Stone I tested with c++. No error is given but it doesn't enter the if statement

Comment: @bpgeck This is weird, since it does print out stuff on my machine.

Comment: If it's not entering the if block, it's probably because `X` is getting the value 0 in your tests, and so the expression evaluates to false.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley it actually failed to compile in `gcc`, but ok with `g++`. The reason was shadowing as you pointed out.

Comment: @artm I checked that C doesn't allow you to define variables in if / for / while conditions.

Answer (score -1):

Change all the 
( Int X =X) to (X) 
It is creating new variables and possibly returning old data stored in that location.

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything here, just to test it's behaviour.