# What is the compiler doing with parameters vs without parameters?

Tags: c++, initialization

I have a non important question about compilers for C++. The following code outputs

```
1
2
3
```

and I can't figure out why. What difference does declaring it with empty parameters make to no parenthesis at all?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    cout << x << endl;

    int y();
    cout << y << endl;

    int z(2);
    cout << z << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler is g++.

Comment: That's undefined behavior.

Comment: `int y();` is a forward function declaration.  This code does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Related [Has C++ standard changed with respect to the use of indeterminate values and undefined behavior in C++14?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801)

Answer (score 4):

The 1st one, `x` is [default initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) with indeterminate value, then `cout << x` leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), means anything is possible.

> Default initialization of non-class variables with automatic and dynamic storage duration produces objects with indeterminate values

The 2nd one, `int y();` declares a function named `y`, which has no argument and returns `int`. For `cout << y`, `y` will decay to function pointer, which could convert to `bool` implicitly and then you'll get `1` (i.e. `true`. You can use `std::boolalpha` like `std::cout << std::boolalpha << y` to get the output `true`).

The 3rd one, `z` is [direct initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) with value `2`, then `cout << z` you'll get `2`.

[LIVE sample with clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Az8zY8uxpiuHgppt), note all the warning messages the compiler gives.

Comment: `int y()` is **not** an example of the most vexing parse. It’s not mentioned on the page you link to; the examples there involve attempts to call functions using arguments that end up being parsed as types. That’s not what’s involved with `int y();`.